# MutationObserver - If no mutation observed, don't display the selected element

Tags: javascript, mutation-observers

I was given the below script to solve an issue on my site where the wrong title was being displayed as the h1 heading on dynamically created pages. It works on pages that auto generate their title element, but some pages don't have titles so the h1 from the previous page remains on the current page. So what I want to do is modify this script so that if the mutation observer does not observe a change to the title element, the h1 is set to display none... Is this possible? Or is there a better way to do it? (And no I cannot just give the pages titles...)

```
new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
 document.querySelector('h1').innerText = mutations[0].target.innerText;
}).observe(
 document.querySelector('title'),
 { subtree: true, characterData: true, attributes: true, childList: true }
);
document.querySelector('h1').innerText = document.querySelector('title').innerText;
```

Comment: Don't use terms like "noob". It's denigrating and unnecessary. Just state your problem as best you can and we'll do what we can to help.

Comment: `target.entry-title` is a syntax error

Comment: Fixed! Thanks @Andrea. I had accidentally left that in after trying a few things